# Parse nested JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I just wanted to ask, how to simply parse nested JSON structure in Java that looks like this:

```
{
   "goods":{
      "NY Store":[
         {
            "product":"Teddybear",
            "available":"20"
         },
         {
            "product":"Mountain bike",
            "available":"0"
         }]
      "LA Store":[
         {
            "product": ....and so on
```

I want to get all the products from all the stores, but the list is quite big (200 stores). Any tips and hints, please?

Comment: Are you attempting to turn these in to POJOs?

Comment: No, I only need to get product name + availibility as 2 Strings and then push tem into a hashmap.

Comment: That's not "nested JSON", that's plain old JSON.  You just parse it.  You can use a fancy-dancy Jacksonesque tool to parse into "POJOs", but you first should learn to just use a simple parser to parse it into Maps and Lists, the navigate through the Maps and Lists to access your data.  This way you'll come to understand JSON much better.

Comment: You'd parse the above into a JSONObject, call it `root`, then do `root.getObject("goods")` to go the first level, producing another JSONObject (call it `goods`).  Then `goods.getArray("NY Store")` to get a JSONArray called `store`.  Then `store.getObject(0)` to get the first element of the array called `storeElement`, then `storeElement.getString("product")` will return "Teddybear".  About 5 lines to fetch "Teddybear", if you put each step on a single line (which is advised, when you're starting out).

Comment: BTW, go to json.org and study the JSON syntax -- it only takes 5- 10 minutes to learn.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick intro for your specific use case into the Jackson library.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;

public class JSONTest {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws JsonMappingException
     * @throws JsonGenerationException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<InventoryItem>> fs = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<InventoryItem>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ArrayList<InventoryItem> its = new ArrayList<InventoryItem>();
            its.add(new InventoryItem("teddy", 20));
            its.add(new InventoryItem("diny", 10));
            fs.put(Long.toString(System.nanoTime()), its);
        }
        StoreContianer g = new StoreContianer(fs);
        ObjectMapper objm = new ObjectMapper();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        objm.writeValue(sw, g);
        System.out.println(sw.toString());
        StoreContianer c = objm.readValue(
                "{\"goods\":{\"55278650620460\":[{\"product\":\"teddy\",\"available\":20},{\"product\":\"diny\",\"available\":10}],\"55278650631327\":[{\"product\":\"teddy\",\"available\":20},{\"product\":\"diny\",\"available\":10}],\"55278650628131\":[{\"product\":\"teddy\",\"available\":20},{\"product\":\"diny\",\"available\":10}],\"55278650582748\":[{\"product\":\"teddy\",\"available\":20},{\"product\":\"diny\",\"available\":10}],\"55278650624615\":[{\"product\":\"teddy\",\"available\":20},{\"product\":\"diny\",\"available\":10}]}}",
                StoreContianer.class);
        StringWriter sw2 = new StringWriter();
        objm.writeValue(sw2, c);
        System.out.println(sw2.toString());
    }
}

@JsonSerialize
class StoreContianer {
    private final HashMap<String, ArrayList<InventoryItem>> goods;

    public StoreContianer(@JsonProperty("goods") HashMap<String, ArrayList<InventoryItem>> goods) {
        this.goods = goods;
    }

    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<InventoryItem>> getGoods() {
        return goods;
    }
}

@JsonSerialize
class InventoryItem {
    private final String product;
    private final int available;

    public InventoryItem(@JsonProperty("product") String product, @JsonProperty("available") int available) {
        this.product = product;
        this.available = available;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public int getAvailable() {
        return available;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use the library? http://www.json.org/java/

specifically,

```
public JSONObject(String source) throws JSONException {
        this(new JSONTokener(source));
}
```

Comment: Meh, that JSON library is pretty lousy for Java. There are much better ones out there, such as GSON or Jackson.

Comment: I tried to iterate through the JSONArray object, but it didn't work.

`JSONObject goods = new JSONObject(jsonInput);
JSONArray stores = goods.toJSONArray("stores");`

throws me an error

Comment: need more information, update your question with some details from this attempt.

Comment: because it is incredible slow

Comment: @MattBall It's not a lousy library; its usefulness depends on what's needed. The JSON in Java library does not require deserializing to a custom class - basic operations are performed using the post-parsing JSONObject which is all the OP needed. If I'm working with a response from a web service then I'll use Jackson and unmarhsal to my own classes but if I need a quick way to manipulate a JSON object directly (and not through my own POJO) I use the JSON in Java library.

Comment: @LukasHanacek My experience is that the library is quite fast, plus it's very lightweight and easily modified.

Comment: @Paul are you aware that Jackson also has a JsonObject class?

Comment: @MattBall, it does not. It has [a rough equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565260/what-is-the-jackson-2-equivalent-of-jsonobject) which is not as straightforward to use as org.json.JSONObject.  Are you aware the JSON in Java library is only 67 KB with no external dependencies while jackson-databind is 1 MB and depends on jackson-core (220 KB) and jackson-annotations (27 KB)? Jackson is a great library - I use it where warranted.  It is not, however, the best tool for every JSON job.

Comment: @PanInkognito - Learn to actually READ the exception messages.  You can often learn quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [google library](https://code.google.com/p/json-path/) very powerful for parsing nested objects in JSON.

`List<String> products = JsonPath.read(json, "$.goods.NY Store[*].product");`

This will return you a list of all products in each "NY Store" list.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //import java.util.ArrayList;
    //import org.bson.Document;

    Document root = Document.parse("{\n"
            + "   \"goods\":{\n"
            + "      \"NY Store\":[\n"
            + "         {\n"
            + "            \"product\":\"Teddybear\",\n"
            + "            \"available\":\"20\"\n"
            + "         },\n"
            + "         {\n"
            + "            \"product\":\"Mountain bike\",\n"
            + "            \"available\":\"0\"\n"
            + "         }]}}");

    System.out.println(((String) ((Document) ((ArrayList) ((Document) root.get("goods")).get("NY Store")).get(0)).get("product")));
    System.out.println(((String) ((Document) ((ArrayList) ((Document) root.get("goods")).get("NY Store")).get(0)).get("available")));
    System.out.println(((String) ((Document) ((ArrayList) ((Document) root.get("goods")).get("NY Store")).get(1)).get("product")));
    System.out.println(((String) ((Document) ((ArrayList) ((Document) root.get("goods")).get("NY Store")).get(1)).get("available")));
```