# What is the Jackson 2 equivalent of JSONObject?

Tags: json, jackson

What class in the fasterxml API is equivalent to the org.json.JSONObject?

Comment: What are you referring to by "codehaus JSONObject"?  Are you looking for ObjectNode? http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html

Comment: I put the wrong package name. Sorry. But it looks like you've answered my question. Thanks.

Comment: Also worth noting is that code can also use more generic `JsonNode` (basetype of `ObjectNode`)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It appears the class sought was `ObjectNode`, not `JSONObject`.

`ObjectNode` is now in the databind project, in the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node` package.  The latest JavaDoc is at http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html

Comment: And if you really need convert the `ObjectNode` to  `JSONobject` you can use it like this `new JSONObject(mObjectNode.toString());`

Comment: A currently valid link is http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html

Answer (score 9):

Jackson 2.x

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode`

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  ObjectNode json = mapper.createObjectNode();
  json.put("error", "json mapping error");
```