# Turning a bean to Json in java

Tags: java, json

I have a class that I want to turn into JSON, but the constructor does not allow me. The class is called CourseKeyInfo:

```
public class CourseKeyInfo
{
    private String courseKey;
    private String institutionID;
    public CourseKeyInfo(String courseKey, String institutionId)
    {
        this.courseKey = courseKey;
        this.institutionID = institutionId;
    }
    public String getCourseKey()
    {
        return courseKey;
    }
    public void setCourseKey(String courseKey)
    {
        this.courseKey = courseKey;
    }
    public String getInstitutionID()
    {
        return institutionID;
    }
    public void setInstitutionID(String institutionID)
    {
        this.institutionID = institutionID;
    }
}
```

I use `JSONObject body = new JSONObject(responseEntity);` to turn it into json but it give me "The constructor JSONObject(CourseKeyInfo) is undefined" error. Any idea how I can turn my class into json?

Comment: Is it this API you are using http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html ?

Comment: If so, it should support this http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.Object%29 It takes Object in constructor

Comment: Nishant you are right. I was using the Jettison implementation and I was not using the right API. I changed it to org.json and it worked.

Comment: is this relevant to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565260/what-is-the-jackson-2-equivalent-of-jsonobject

Answer (score 4):

The constructor [JSONObject(Object)](http://javadox.com/org.json/json/20151123/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.Object-) does actually exist.

```
CourseKeyInfo courseKeyInfo = new CourseKeyInfo("This Works!", "101");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(courseKeyInfo);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), you can do this is one line as:

```
CourseKeyInfo courseKeyInfo = new CourseKeyInfo("This Works!", "101");
String json = new Gson().toJson(courseKeyInfo);
System.out.println(json);
```

for this to work

- download [GSON JAR](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/files/google-gson-2.2.2-release.zip)
- Add to your project build path
- That's all

and the result is:

```
{"courseKey":"This Works!","institutionID":"101"}
```

Answer (score 1):

for http request here is example of using json array+ json beans

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for (Credentials credentials : ((PropertiesManager) propertiesManager.get()).getJsonPropertiesManager().getAllCredentials()) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("credentialsName", credentials.getName());
        jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
    }

    req.setAttribute(JSON_RESULT_OBJ_ATTR, jsonArray.toString());
```