# Use Jackson to create simple objects like JSON.org

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to use Jackson to create simple JSON objects where I am not required to build custom classes for every response but rather a premade object similar to the code below. Other JSON libraries (android, JSON.org, GSON) you can do something similar to this

```
JsonObject myObject = new JsonObject("{\"a\":1}");
myObject.getInt("a"); // returns 1
```

I cant seem to find a similar operation in the Jackson packages. **PS**: I know I can create an java class to encapsulate this specific JSON string but what I am looking for is a way to create generic JSON objects that I DONT need to parse into a classes that I have defined. I cant seem to find anything on the internet that points me to something similar to this. I have a feeling this is outside Jacksons realm and they do not support operations like this. If this is the case just say so and I will close the question.

My goal is to not have another Json library in my project.

---

**Edit 2014:** I found you can use the class `org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode` that will hold your object and allow you to do operations as described in my question.

Heres a code sample:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode myObject = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree("{\"a\":1}");
System.out.println(myObject.get("a").asInt()); // prints 1
```

Comment: Looks to me like you want a `Map` - here's a [little tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/). Java is a type safe language, you cannot have dynamic objects like you have in javaScript for example. Otherwise have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11582130/2071828) about `ObjectNode`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks for the suggestion however I just tested that example against more dynamic objects like {myProp:2, nestedObject:{innerValue:1, innerValue:2}} and got errors(left out " for space). Took a look at the 2nd link you sent and cant seem to parse a string into it. I was looking at that class and other classes in that package prior to making this post but got nowhere.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Whoops... I posted to soon before going through all the solutions on mykongs blog *facepalm. Mind posting an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Ha, rookie error. Done.

Comment: @ug_ in line 2, you don't need to cast the result to ObjectNode, JsonNode is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like you need a `Map`. If you have a simple JSON structure then you can use a `Map<String, String>` like so:

```
String json = "{\"name\":\"mkyong\", \"age\":\"29\"}";
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try { 
    //convert JSON string to Map
    map = mapper.readValue(json, 
        new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>>(){});
    System.out.println(map);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you have a more complex JSON structure with nested objets and what not, then you can use a `Map<String, Object>`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// read JSON from a file
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(
    new File("c:\\user.json"),
    new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
});
System.out.println(map.get("name"));
System.out.println(map.get("age"));
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) map.get("messages");
```

Examples taken from the ever useful [Mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/).